# How to change script pane and result window in PowerShell Screen

Tags: powershell

I want the script pane to be left and the result screen to be on right.
How to change it?
I can see the options only like

- Move script pane to top
- Move Script pane to right
- Show Script Pane Maximized

[image: PowerShell screen]

#### Update:

I have raised a feature request/enhancement request in GitHub, could all of the community members upvote this - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17240. Thank you for your support!

Comment: You should consider moving form ISE to VS Code with it's PowerShell extension. Re. your question, there doesn't seem to be an option to move the script pane to the left.

Comment: VS Code is rather awesome. But is very buggy. Currently I can't get PowerShell output unless I write-host. This isn't viable for every command in a script. And is rather frustrating. - maybe visual studio community?

Comment: I have raised a feature request/enhancement request in GitHub, could all of the community members upvote this - https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17240. Thank you for your support!

Comment: You have raised an issue to the PoweShell Core team, they don't maintain ISE, in fact, nobody maintains it. Microsoft has already recommended to not use ISE anymore and to start using VS Code.

Comment: Hello @SantiagoSquarzon, but Robert Cotterman said that it is very buggy and frustrating from his experience. What do you suggest for this?

Comment: That's his opinion, I didn't have any issues with VS Code.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, actually I'm new to PowerShell, VS Code Development Tools - So asking your suggestion!

Comment: To put it simple, there will be more people (much more) willing to help you with any issue you have with VS Code than there will be with ISE. VS Code is open source as well as it's powershell extension, regularly maintained and devs responsive to issues.

Comment: He's right, my opinion and experiences are mine. I really do wanna like VS Code. But I have tried to use it for Python and PowerShell. Both have had unexpected bugs that frustrate me to no end. I have co-workers who are annoyed by some of the same bugs but still prefer it over ise. ‍♂️

Comment: Heartily Thankful to both of you! You have given me immense knowledge! I have started to use the VS Code. As of now, I started to learn PowerShell Commands so it is working excellently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell ISE only has 3 options. And there's no viable way to choose another. It's not the answer we want. It's the answer we have.

The options are

> Show Script Pane Top  -  Moves the Script Pane to the top in the display.

> Show Script Pane Right  -  Moves the Script Pane to the right in the display.

> Show Script Pane Maximized  -  Maximizes the Script Pane.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/exploring-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.2